# IDisposable Pattern - Is Dispose() invoked when an object is stored in a Thread local data?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

All,

I have a class `FileLogger` that implements `IDisposable` pattern. The instance of this class is stored in current thread's local data:

```
LocalDataStoreSlot s;
s = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("logger");

if (Thread.GetData(s) == null)
    Thread.SetData(s, new FileLogger());
```

Nowhere in the code I call `Dispose()` on my class but when the process ends, the finalizer is not invoked. Here's the implementation of the `IDisposable` pattern in my class:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_isDisposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {   
        }

            try
            {
                closeFile_();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

~FileLogger()
{
    Dispose(false);
}
```

`closeFile_()` method is never invoked (I know it is not being invoked because this method should write into the file some closing html tags). Why?

Comment: How do you know the Finalizer is not called?  Be aware your call to Dispose from there is with false so the code that calls closeFile_ isn't executed then.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that oversight, I corrected the code in the posting by moving out the closeFile_() outside the if (disposing). Nevertheless, when the process ends, I know closeFile_() never is invoked because that method should write into the file some closing html tags. I added this to my posting.

Comment: Read the second note in the documentation about Finalizer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers

Comment: And then create your your own cleanup code afterwards. The paragraph after the mentioned note has a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Ralf, that answers it: in .net core Finalizers are not called when application terminates. LOL, I am coming from .net framework so this is news to me. Not sure what to  make of this.  Sometimes, the explicit code to do clean up is not as easy because of the deep nesting of certain instances, which means, you have to write dispose methods on outer classes to dispose the nested objects. I am not sure how I feel about the changes in Finalizers in .net. Previously, you were safe just writing the finalizer, now not anymore. In addition, imagine porting code from .net framework to .net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Ralf:

NET 5 (including .NET Core) and later versions don't call finalizers as part of application termination.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers)

Comment: The problem is the code, not the finalizers. Either you have a nesting bug in `if (disposing){  }` or you have a finalization bug because you try to write to a file at a point where this is no longer possible. The whole point of the `disposing` parameter is to prevent actions that can't succeed during finalization. Your code never calls `Dispose()` so there's no expectation that `closefile_` will be called.

Comment: Since you used `ActiveX` as a name, what you try to do is call an ActiveX object after the final Release. Your app will crash abruptly even though it was shutting down gracefully by that point

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes and No. Commenting here on specific scenario: The file can easily outlive the application, ex: Log file. The log file once created will existing during app's run time and after the app has ended or terminated. At any point in time you still can access the file, and it is safe because it is guaranteed to exist when the app starts. This idea of resources outliving an application is less common but possible/logical in certain circumstances.

Comment: The file yes. The file handle no. The finalizer is only called when an object is being garbage-collected, at which point anything else it points to may already be disposed. That's why `disposing` is used, to identify this case. There's no guarantee how long it will be before a GC - on a server this may take quite a while. The guidance is clear ever since `IDisposable` was introduced - don't use finalizer to do any real job, only use them to clean up unmanaged resources. There are a **lot** of SO questions caused by people disregarding this and trying to access disposed objects

Comment: I 100% agree with your point but ... with a file though, you don't need a handle to it, you just need the file path to access it and there are routines to write to it ex, AppendAllText(). Is writing a closing tags to a file considered real work and unsafe? I would say it depends on your scenario, and can be debated.

Comment: I can only see a problem if the path string was already de-allocated which would cause a problem but ... if it is a class static or constant, the strings should stay allocated until the entire process unloads after all finalizers run? But I still agree with your comments, it is a bad practice to do pretty much do anything else but release handles to resources.